# Can't write in input fields only in safari

Tags: html, css, forms, input, safari

On my website people somehow cannot write in the inputs when they use Safari. The problem is only present in safari.
(http://www.rootshybrid.dk/blivfrivillig/)

From other threads I've seen the solution being the `user-select` code. I have tried adding both `webkit-user-select: auto;` and `webkit-user-select: text;` to the css of the input fields, but it still doesn't work.

Anyone have a solution to my problem?

Comment: I am able to write in them using Safari 8.0.2.
http://imgur.com/a/dTCzF

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please visit the [help] to see what and how to ask. Right now your question is not useful to anyone but yourself. When you change your site, the issue is gone. Please create a [mcve] here

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The combination input padding on line 40 of main.css

```
input, select, textarea {
    border-radius: 6px;
    border: 1px solid #d0d0d0;
    outline: 0;
    font-family: Roboto;
    padding: 15px 10px;  /*<<<<<<<*/
    font-size: 15px;
    webkit-user-select: auto;
}
```

Is not working with the height on line 55 and 80 of main.css

```
.whitebox input[type="text"] {
    height: 20px;
}
```

Comment: So... the question is not useful to anyone but the OP. How about your answer?

Comment: I have no problem with the question being deleted.

Answer (score 0):

Just add a hollow class to the `<p>` value
for example

```
<p class="abc">
  <label class="stdlabel">Fornavn *</label>
  <input type="text" name="firstname" value="">
</p>
```

Because it seems that the problem occurs for those input labels only